# Fully Healing after being Stilled/Gentled

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

So when someone who has been stilled/gentled is healed by someone of the same gender, they are only healed to 1/3rd of their original power. If, after being healed to 1/3rd of their original power, they are stilled/gentled again and then healed by a member of opposite sex, can they recover 100% of their original power?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Very interesting question - what counts as "original" power after a second stilling/gentling? But I suspect there's no canon answer. Even in-universe this would make sense, since AFAIK there's nobody who's _been_ stilled/gentled twice. So the answer is probably "no way of telling", but maybe someone will come up with a relevant quote.

Comment: I got the impression when I was reading, that you could restore someone to their pre-stilled power, but the weave needs to be different for women than for men. Nynaeve used the exact same weave to heal Siuan and Leane that she did for Logain, which, while it worked, reduced their power. I think if she had spent more time thinking about it and tweaking it, she could have healed them back to their previous power. But this is all speculation on my part.

Comment: Thanks Rand. By original power I mean the level of the One Power they could channel before being severed the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the mouth of Robert Jordan himself, "RAFO", for those unsure what this means, read and find out, was Jordan's response to questions that were either spoilers or he himself had not yet decided.

> QUESTION:
>
> Siuan and Leane being stilled again and Healed by a male to full
>   strength...
>
> ROBERT JORDAN
>
> "RAFO, because I might decide to use that as a plot device!" (That got
>   a few chuckles).

[Number 13](http://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=Stilled)
So we know Jordan thought about this, however, he died before ever confirming what would happen.

This quote leads me to believe though, that it would be possible to heal someone again, and to full power, he was just debating actually using this in the plot or not.

Also [Number 10](http://www.theoryland.com/intvsresults.php?kw=healing) Confirms OP's claim that healing done by the opposite gender is required for 100% healing.

> ROBERT JORDAN
>
> For Alys Kinch, the Healing of stilling must be done by the other
>   gender to be fully effective. A woman Healing a woman or a man Healing
>   a man results in less than full restoration. It all ties into that
>   theme I keep harping on. Men and women have to work together to be
>   their most effective. And while the weave used by Flinn for Healing is
>   not exactly that used by Nynaeve, either would use the same weave on a
>   man or a woman.

Comment: Note that the novels may be finished but there are still rumors of a WoT encyclopedia, to include informatin from Jordan's notes that never made it into the books. Perhaps there will be an explanation of severing and healing it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield there not rumors tor has a release date for it in November 2015 i believe. until then this is as good as OP can get after scrolling through about 10 pages of interviews about gentling and stilling lol. http://www.tor.com/2015/01/07/wheel-of-time-companion-cover-release-date/

Comment: Very nice effore Himarm. So apparently we are to wait till (and if) there's a WoT encyclopedia released by Tor.

Comment: @6packkid This is the answer, from his own words, its only speculative if the encyclopedia will expand on this, the interview i pulled this from is right before he got sick so im not sure if you should wait around and hope.

Answer (score 1):

In *The Wheel of Time Companion*, we finally get a canon-answer to healing being 100% effective, rather than just the interview quotes or educated guesses we were previously left with. (Interview quotes from Jordan were sometimes subject to change).

Under the entry for Logain Ablar:

> Logain was accidentally Healed by Nynaeve; the rebel Aes Sedai held him prisioner while they decided whether or not they could afford to gentle him again, give Rand and his amnesty. Since Leane and Siuan were not as strong as they once were after being Healed, the rebel Aes Sedai assumed that Logain wasn't either; **none of them knew that this Healing needed the opposite sex for completeness. In fact, because he had been Healed by a woman, he was just as strong as ever**.

We also see that Damer Flinn healed three Aes Sedai that were stilled at Dumai Wells, and they didn't seem to be any worse for the wear.

We are never given any evidence that anything special happens when gentling/stilling someone that's already been Healed of the same affliction.

It never happens in the books, so Jordan's "RAFO" meant that we actually "find out" nothing. We can only assume that:

1. They'll be healed to their original power levels, as it'd be like taking a poorly-fit bandage and putting a proper one on
2. They'll only be healed to their post-Healing levels, as the first healing capped them

Unless additional materials are published, we'll never know. The *Companion* was the last major addition to The Wheel of Time planned, and Robert Jordan is no longer with us to give Word of God answer.

Comment: OK, the *Companion* is officially crap. "the rebel Aes Sedai assumed that Logain wasn't either" is just wrong. They're aware right from the start (LoC chapter 30) that he's as strong as he ever was. I'll find the relevant quotes later.

Comment: Also, this isn't an answer to the question. The OP is perfectly aware that "when someone who has been stilled/gentled is healed by someone of the same gender, they are only healed to 1/3rd of their original power"; they're asking whether such a person could then be stilled/gentled again and *re*-Healed by someone of the opposite gender to their original power. Your answer doesn't address this issue.

Comment: @randal'thor 1) There's speculation about his strength from Nynaeve, but it's not the rebel group as a whole who voice it. 2) The *Companion* foreword indicates possible errors. Maybe a future edition will fix discrepancies. 3) You're right, I updated it.

Comment: I think the point number 2 in the answer above might be as close to an answer to this question as we can get. It seems logical to assume that if a person is stilled, they can only be healed to the level of strength they were stilled at no matter how many times they have been healed/stilled previously.

Answer (score 1):

Being healed of stilling by someone of the same sex can't be fixed. Nyneave specifically tells Siuan and Leave when they ask her to try again that what has already been Healed cannot be Healed again.